# How to detect if a store listed in google maps has business view (see inside 360 tours)?

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-places

Would be great if you help me out finding a way to detect if a store have business view or not.
I gathered a list of places with place_id and I was expecting some business view data to show up performing a "place detail request" but I can't spot the right parameter.

Example: this store has business view

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJpwX5jddQqEcRxg3UN_d-DJc&key=YOUR GOOGLE API KEY

Comment: Can't see what your example looks like because a valid key is required.  Can you paste in whatever Google's response is to your question please?

Comment: Sure. This:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3R7cW7MntxjbHNOUThDcEdBbVE/view?usp=sharing

and the store google+ page is:
https://plus.google.com/108222573883185092353/about?hl=en-US

Comment: It's right there in the response: `"url" : "https://plus.google.com/108222573883185092353/about?hl=en­US",`

Comment: Thanks duncan but it's not what I'm asking. Maybe I wasn't clear enough. 
What I need to know is if that place has business view ("see inside" tours) or not.

Comment: There's nothing documented: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details_responses

Comment: All right. Thanks anyways. Then I'll just look for  <span>see inside</> on each google+ page.

Comment: yeah, you could maybe do an AJAX request and then parse the page for that string